# Posting Data to Server with volley library from android App

Tags: java, android, networking, python-requests, android-volley

Guys i need help am trying to post this data to my server here but it is returning an error, it seems to be working just fine in postman the problem comes in while trying to implement in android app using google's volley library.

[Link](http://yoyo.coderows.nl/rest/save_inventory.php) to server script.

This is the screenshot of a successful post working in postman rest client:[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXsGf.png)

```
private void SaveDataToServer() {

    StringRequest serverPostRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.SAVE_INVENTORY_URL,

            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String json) {
                    try {
                        Toast.makeText(SelectItemsActivity.this, json.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER",json);
                        JSONObject dataJson=new JSONObject(json);
                        JSONObject myJson=dataJson.getJSONObject("status");
                        String status=myJson.getString("status_text");
                        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Success.")){
                            Toast.makeText(SelectItemsActivity.this, "Data saved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            proggressShow.dismiss();
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(SelectItemsActivity.this, "An error occured while saving data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            proggressShow.dismiss();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {


        }

    }){

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getPostParams()  {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("api_key",Config.API_KEY);
            params.put("move_id", "1");
            params.put("room_name", "Attic room");
            params.put("item_name", "Halloween Broom");
            params.put("item_id", "6");
            Log.e("datat to server",params.toString());
            return params;
        }
    };
    saveDataRequest.add(serverPostRequest);
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting??

Comment: @sumit the error is that i cant save the data to database from android side using volley that i have implemented using the java code above, i can save the data using postman as illustrated in the image above.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding getHeaders method in your request

```
  @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                final HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
                return headers;
            }
```

Comment: 06-21 11:42:35.518 6705-6705/ke.co.ipandasoft.cubemovers E/RESPONSE FROM SERVER: {"status":{"status_code":"3","status_text":"Invalid Access"}}

Comment: its supposed to give success if the post is successful just as in postman in image above.

Comment: It seems you are sending something wrong in your parameters please check all the values you have passed in getParams method

Comment: this are the items

Comment: @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams()  {
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("api_key",Config.API_KEY);
                params.put("move_id", "1");
                params.put("room_name", "Attic room");
                params.put("item_name", "Halloween Broom");
                params.put("item_id", "6");
                return params;
            }

Comment: Same items it the postman image above that the server is accepting

Answer (score 0):

After adding this lines to my request headers i was able to successfully commit the database to my db.
Also i made sure i am using a stringRequest for a jsonRequest it does not work for reasons i do not know.

```
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return headers;
        }
```